# Different results from Tensorflow and Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I get different results from Tensorflow and Keras with the same network structure.

The loss function looks like

```
class MaskedMultiCrossEntropy(object):
    def loss(self, y_true, y_pred):
        vec = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_pred, labels=y_true, dim=1)
        mask = tf.equal(y_true[:,0,:], -1)
        zer = tf.zeros_like(vec)
        loss = tf.where(mask, x=zer, y=vec)
        return loss
```

The network layer I used is called CrowdsClassification, which is implemented by Keras. Then I build the network by

```
x = Dense(128, input_shape=(input_dim,), activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(N_CLASSES)(x)
x = Activation("softmax")(x)
crowd = CrowdsClassification(num_classes, num_oracles, conn_type="MW")
x = crowd(x)
```

Train the model with Keras

```
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss)
model.fit(inputs,
           true_class, epochs=100, shuffle=False, verbose=2, validation_split=0.1))
```

Train the model with tensorflow

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01, beta1=0.9, beta2=0.999)
opt_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for epoch in range(100):
    sess.run([loss, opt_op], feed_dict=train_feed_dict)
```

The Tensorflow will get a wrong prediction. It seems that the issue comes from the loss function, that Tensorflow cannot backproporgate the masked loss. Anyone can give some advices? Thx a lot.

Comment: Did you try using the default parameter for Adam?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but it didn't work.